# Extracting optionValue from postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to find all addresses from a wp database so I select all rows having `metakey = mkd_portfolios` having `opionLabel = Address` from postmeta table.

But I can't find how to extract items in meta_value.
I guess  it is something easy with php?

```
meta_value : a:1:{i:0;a:4:
 {s:11:""optionLabel"";s:7:""Address"";s:11:""optionValue"";s:21:""Dune du Pilat, 
  France"";s:9:""optionUrl"";s:0:"""";s:22:""optionlabelordernumber"";s:1:""1"";}}
```

> meta_id: 15361
>
> post_id: 11428

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`WP_Meta_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) class.

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'optionLabel',
        'value'   => 'Address',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

You might want to further narrow down your results via the `AND` relation in the query, I can not tell from the code you posted. Find more info at the link provided.